# has_rdoc is deprecated warning message after doing bundle update

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

Just finished updating my bundler and now I keep getting this messages:

NOTE: Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#has_rdoc= called from /Users/eumir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@waftt/bundler/gems/watir-9e41fd458687/watir/watir.gemspec:43

I've googled for this eror and all it returns are pages to agile web development(looks like a tutorial but it has all the errors pasted in it...weird)

http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot-193-30/section-10.1.html

Anyway, is the only way to turn this off, going into each of my "outdated" gems' gemspecs and takign out that has_rdoc thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this error because the [Gemspec for Watir](https://github.com/bret/watir/blob/master/watir/watir.gemspec#L43) calls `has_rdoc`, which is deprecated in the latest RubyGems API.

I'd imagine by the time `has_rdoc` is removed from the API, the Watir team will have removed this call.

This warning does not affect your app or your tests, so can be safely ignored for now.

Comment: yes i know they can't affect my app or tests...just kinda getting annoyed(there are like 10 gems we are using that throw this error along with another one)...do i just wait for them to fix it or is editing the gemspec okay?

Comment: Just wait for them to fix it. There are probably more productive things to be worrying about.

Comment: Of course, most of these projects are on Github and would gladly accept patches to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly downgrade rubygems back to a version that has not yet deprecated has_rdoc.

Rubygems is progressing [super rapidly](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rubygems-developers/2011-June/thread.html) at the moment, and if you don't want to deal with more issues in other gems until the authors of the gems catch up, you might want to integrate rubygems versioning into your deployments/development provisioning strategy.

`gem update --system 1.6.9 #has_rdoc is deprecated beginning in 1.7.0` (1)

[1](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rubygems-developers/2011-June/thread.html) https://github.com/thoughtafter/simple-rss/pull/1

Answer (score -1):

Updating *rubygems* did it for me

```
sudo gem update --system
```